# как в Intellij IDEA убрать зеленое подчеркивание слова

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Доброго времени суток 0/
Подскажите, как в Intellij IDEA убрать зеленое подчеркивание для конкретного слова в моём случае Complect/complect ? Не скажу что сильно мешает, но мозолит глаза точно
[image: назойливое подчеркивание]

Comment: 1. Добавить в словарь. 2. Отключить проверку вообще. Всё делается через alt+enter (в win, как на маке не знаю)

Comment: alt+enter на этом слове, потом в выпадающем списке выбери disable inspection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

Первый, выключить проверку грамматики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй способ, добавить слово в исключение, если его нет в словаре. Это делается выставление курсора на указанное слово и нажатием комбинации клавиш "ALT+ENTER"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну, отключать совсем грамматику не хочу, а вот второй вариант мне подходит. Спасибо!